# Why does my code list out even these?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a search function, which lists out the products that meet the search criteria.

```
termekek = products
marka = manufacturer
tipus = type
```

As you can see on the image below, it lists out my products which are MSI but are not Radeon as well.
It should only list ou the products, that are MSi but Radeon as well. The problem must be with my SQL code in my opinion, but I can't seem to get it right.
Thank you in advance!
[image: My problem]

My PHP code:

http://pastebin.com/fmwLVbER

```
           <?php

            if(isset($_GET["text_search"]))
            {
                require('db.php');
                mysql_select_db('ceg',$connection);
                $text=$_GET["text_search"];

                $text=explode(" ", $text);

                $i=1;

                if(count($text) > 0)
                    $sql='SELECT * FROM termekek WHERE marka="'.$text[0].'" OR tipus="'.$text[0].'" ';

                while($i < count($text)){
                    $sql .= 'AND marka="'.$text[$i].'" OR tipus="'.$text[$i].'"';
                    $i++;
                }

                echo $sql;

                $result=mysql_query($sql);

                if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                    while($array=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                        echo '<div id="product">
                            <div>
                                <img height="250" width="250" src='.$array["kep"].' />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                '.$array["marka"].'
                                '.$array["tipus"].'
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                '.$array["ar"].' euró
                            </div>
                          </div>';
                    }
                }
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: [SQL Injection Alert](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: MySQL deprecation alert as well.

Comment: Eisa is saying that if you don't scrub the inputs then there's the possiblity of sql injections. Try using this on your data before adding it to your sql statement. mysql_real_escape_string( )

Comment: oh yea, I see the problem now, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parentheses around your OR clauses, so that they get evaluated first.

Comment: Thanks, mate! I totally forgot to try that. x)

Answer (score 0):

Based on what Robert has said, I think your code should look like this.

```
if(count($text) > 0)
                    $sql='SELECT * FROM termekek WHERE (marka="'.$text[0].'" OR tipus="'.$text[0].'") ';

                while($i < count($text)){
                    $sql .= 'AND (marka="'.$text[$i].'" OR tipus="'.$text[$i].'")';
                    $i++;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you as well, it is working now. :) Of course I need parantheses, else it will be just sequental.